# why did the console'log had a attribute(length) , and this 'length' would not output in foreach?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Here is my code:

```
 var obj = {}; [].push.call(obj, "a"); 
 console.log(obj);
 //output:{0:"a",length:1} what length? 

 [].forEach.call(obj, function(v, i, a) {
     console.log(i);
    //output: 0
    //Although this obj had two attributes, but only echoed once. 
 });
```

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you think you could also provide some context on what you're trying to do? I think it'd help people to understand the problem you're having.

Comment: Thanks for your help~~~~~~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because the [Array `forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does only iterate indices (integer-named properties), not all properties. In fact it does need the `.length` property to know *when to stop iterating* :-)

Comment: Thanks! But i couldnt understanded  with example.1 , why it had "length" ?

Comment: Because `push()` increases the `.length` by 1, and creates the property if it didn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much,and then i try it!